# Can a class observe multiple observables?

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

If a Class that is Implementing Observer can Observe multiple Observable Classes, how will the class know which Observable class has changed?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Observer {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ObservableClass1 oc1 = new ObservableClass1();
        oc1.addObserver(this);
        ObservableClass2 oc2 = new ObservableClass2();
        oc2.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {

        //How will I know which observable hasChanged?
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any method on the `observable` to compare or know its class name.

Or should I use

```
observable.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

and make a String comparison?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Observing multiple observables while avoiding instanceof operator in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350508/observing-multiple-observables-while-avoiding-instanceof-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `instanceof` operator to check which `Observable` class called an update, eg:

```
     @Override
     public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {

       if (observable instanceof ObservableClass1) {
          //prcess ObservableCLass1 update here
       } else if (observable instanceof ObservableClass2) {
          //process ObservableClass update here
       } else {
          //some default action or error
       }
    }
```

Comment: No, java cann't cast Observable to another class, then this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible . java observable object can be cast to its sub class and in this way you can achive this ( using instanceof operator )